# Error in Visual Basic loop

Tags: vb.net

Apparently i got it wrong in the second if condition of the loop, i leave a picture for better understanding.

For some reason the error is not displayed in the first if condition even tho they are pretty much the same.

To put this in context i have a big first textbox and other 9 small ones. Basically i want to send the value i write in the big textbox to the small ones one by one.

Big TextBox name attribute is t0 while the others go from t1 to t9

**VISUAL BASIC CODE**

```
 Public Class Form1

        Dim array() As TextBox = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9}

        Private Sub t0_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles t0.KeyDown
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

                If sender.Text.ToString <> String.Empty Then

                    For indice As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1

                        If array(indice).Text = String.Empty Then '<== The error is in this line

                            array(indice).Text = sender.Text.ToString

                            Exit For

                        End If

                    Next

                End If

            End If

        End Sub

    End Class
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Used equals this time but still the same error

Comment: so, your array doesn't seem to have this index or the value is null ;)

Comment: You are right, what is the correct way of declaring an array of textboxs, there is obviusly something wrong with mine. Note that i changed my textbox elements name to t0 up to t9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An item of your `array` seems to be `Nothing`. You can avoid such an error by using the following `if` condition (using `AndAlso`):

```
If TypeOf(array(indice)) Is TextBox AndAlso array(indice).Text = String.Empty Then
    array(indice).Text = sender.Text.ToString
    Exit For
End If
```

**Note:** Your first `if` condition doesn't use the `array` so the error doesn't happen there.

But the problem isn't the `if` condition! You defined the `array` to early. At the time you defined the `array` the controls of the form are not initialized (so every control is `Nothing` until `InitializeComponent` in method / constructor `New` is called).

You can initialize the `array` directly on the `KeyDown` event to make sure the `TextBox` elements are created / initialized.

```
Private Sub t0_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles t0.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If sender.Text.ToString <> String.Empty Then
            Dim array() As TextBox = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9}

            For indice As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
                If TypeOf(array(indice)) Is TextBox AndAlso array(indice).Text = String.Empty Then
                    array(indice).Text = sender.Text.ToString
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Another solution to use the `array` globally too, is to initialize the `array` on the form `Load` event.

Comment: You are right, my array indexes seem to be null, what is the correct way of declaring an array of textbox? Note that i changed my textboxs name attributes to t0 up to t9

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works as expected, i put the declaration in the load method and works well too, is there any explanation why it doesnt work declaring the array out of the form methods.

Comment: Saw the update, i understand now, as in android there are methods that are called automatically and will load the interface and components, so you can not reference those components before they are loaded. Thanks!